# ImportError: cannot import name 'Pdb' from 'IPython.core.debugger'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

It seems I can't use Jupyter notebook at all. I've already tried to uninstall and install again but this error persists.

> [I 19:33:14.916 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5),
>   new random ports Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py",
>   line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py",
>   line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line
>   15, in 
>       from ipykernel import kernelapp as app   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/**init**.py", line
>   2, in 
>       from .connect import *   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line
>   13, in 
>       from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/**init**.py", line 54,
>   in 
>       from .core.application import Application   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from IPython.core import release, crashhandler   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       from IPython.core import ultratb   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line
>   115, in 
>       from IPython.core import debugger   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pdb.py",
>   line 76, in 
>       import code   File "/Users/robot/Dropbox/coding/ytautomator/temp/testing_code/code.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line
>   1209, in subplots
>       fig = figure(**fig_kw)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line
>   545, in figure
>       **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",
>   line 3251, in new_figure_manager
>       fig = fig_cls(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line
>   367, in **init**
>       FigureCanvasBase(self)  # Set self.canvas.   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",
>   line 1582, in **init**
>       self._fix_ipython_backend2gui()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",
>   line 1609, in _fix_ipython_backend2gui
>       ip = IPython.get_ipython()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/getipython.py",
>   line 22, in get_ipython
>       from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 46, in 
>       from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb ImportError: cannot import name 'Pdb' from 'IPython.core.debugger'
>   (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py)

I'm using Python 3.7.4 with Anaconda in Mac OS 10.14.6

My pip free is the following:

```
appnope==0.1.0
attrs==19.3.0
backcall==0.1.0
bleach==3.1.0
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.4.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
entrypoints==0.3
importlib-metadata==0.23
ipdb==0.12.2
ipykernel==5.1.2
ipython==7.8.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.15.1
Jinja2==2.10.3
json5==0.8.5
jsonschema==3.1.1
jupyter-client==5.3.4
jupyter-core==4.6.0
jupyterlab==1.1.4
jupyterlab-server==1.0.6
kiwisolver==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.1.1
mistune==0.8.4
more-itertools==7.2.0
nbconvert==5.6.0
nbformat==4.4.0
notebook==6.0.1
numpy==1.17.2
pandas==0.25.1
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.5.1
pexpect==4.7.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==2.0.10
ptyprocess==0.6.0
Pygments==2.4.2
pyparsing==2.4.2
pyrsistent==0.15.4
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.3
pyzmq==18.1.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.12.0
terminado==0.8.2
testpath==0.4.2
tornado==6.0.3
traitlets==4.3.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
zipp==0.6.0
```

I'd be glad if anyone can help

Thanks

Comment: have you solved this issue? did the answer below work? please try to respond with voting/accepting the answer or provide your own so as to get closure.

Answer (score 15):

Remove the file `code.py` in your folder. It causes a confliction.

Comment: Naming a file `code.py` is such a bad idea. It's like calling a variable `int` or `list`.

Comment: currently ipython kernel refuses even to start with a `code.py` in working directory for it "shadows" an internal module to cause "a module name conflict". *but* this wont happen outside the jupyter kernel, and ipython happily works with such file in current directory.

Comment: Wow, changing the name from `code.py` to something else fixed it.