# unable to run the python code in a virtual environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The kernel failed to start as

> 'InterruptiblePdb' could not be imported from 'most likely due to a circular import'.

I am trying to run a python code in a virtual environment but I'm getting this error. Can anyone tell me what to do?

I have installed all the correct dependencies but still I am unable to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

These are factors have been cause this issue one is circular imports this will happen when two or more modules depend on each other and another possible is you accidentally exiting a virtual environment while installing, be careful in writing a filename It might cause you an error I've found something similar problem to you and might be [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399943/importerror-cannot-import-name-pdb-from-ipython-core-debugger)